# How to make divs that are nested inside another div NOT move when increasing window size

Tags: html, css

Here are these elements at 100% screen size:
[image]

Here they are at 110%:

[image]

CSS:

```
#menu_nav_item {
       
        margin-right: 70px;
        font-size: 28px;
    }

    .menu_nav_item1 {
        
        display: inline-block;
        margin-top: 15px;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div  class="col-lg-6" id="menu_buttons">


            <center style="padding-top:150px">
                <div id="menu_container" style="min-width:300px;">
                    <div class="menu_nav_item1"><a id="menu_nav_item" href="https://cvent.me/L4k0Nm" class="jump-link" data-feathr-click-track="true">ATTEND</a></div>
                    <div class="menu_nav_item1"><a id="menu_nav_item" href="https://cvent.me/L4k0Nm" class="jump-link" data-feathr-click-track="true">PROGRAM</a></div>
                    <div class="menu_nav_item1"><a id="menu_nav_item" href="https://cvent.me/L4k0Nm" class="jump-link" data-feathr-click-track="true">EXPO</a></div>

                    <div  class="menu_nav_item1">
                        <a id="menu_nav_item" href="https://cvent.me/L4k0Nm" class="btn-primary" style="border-radius: 0px!important; padding:20px;" data-feathr-click-track="true"><b>REGISTER NOW</b></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </center>
        </div>
```

**My Question:** How do I stop the menu items from moving when increasing window size %, or when making the screen smaller?

Thanks!

Comment: Shifting navbar elements down like this is generally the desired behaviour for smaller screens. However, you may want to look into a `navbar-collapse` (likely already triggered on your narrower widths). The general approach to styling content at different widths is to make use of `media query` breakpoints. It looks like you're using Bootstrap, which has some built in by default, which you can make use of. If you want them to stay absolutely fixed, you can use `position: fixed`, though keep in mind this may make them go off the screen if you don't adjust their position manually to compensate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using px in code
#menu_nav_item {

```
    margin-right: 70px;
    font-size: 28px;
}

.menu_nav_item1 {
    
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

make use of % like this

#menu_nav_item {

```
    margin-right: 70%;
    font-size: 28%;
}

.menu_nav_item1 {
    
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 15%;
}
```